# MaterialApp doesn't respond to State changes in Flutter Riverpod after Navigating to another screen

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a flutter app with the following Screens:

Login Screen, "Not Connected" Screen, Validation Screen, Main Screen

I Monitor 2 things in the MainApp, **Authentication** and **Connection** Status (Connected to mobile/wifi networks).

When I'm in the Login Screen if the user turns off the data and wifi the MaterialApp is rebuilt and the "Not Connected" Screen appears. The same thing happens if I'm in the Validation Screen.

When I navigate from the Validation screen to the Main Screen, the MaterialApp stops responding to changes in the state of **Authentication** and **Connection**.

I've created a DartPad Sample [**Demonstration**](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2febaf9a6a21ea926327ed86ec6e0a8f)

Here is a Sample Code that will demonstrate the issue:

I'm using the latest Flutter (3.13.8) and the following pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MainAppState createState() => MainAppState();
}

class MainAppState extends ConsumerState<MainApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final connection = ref.watch(connectionProvider);
    final auth = ref.watch(authProvider);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: getHome(connection, auth),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/main-screen": (ctx) => const MainScreen(),
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getHome(ConnectionProvider connection, AuthProvider auth) {
    if (!connection.isConnected) {
      return const NoConnectionScreen();
    }

    if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
      return const LoginScreen();
    }

    return const CheckScreen();
  }
}

final connectionProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<ConnectionProvider>((ref) {
  return ConnectionProvider();
});

class ConnectionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isConnected = true;

  bool get isConnected => _isConnected;

  Future<void> toggleConnection() async {
    _isConnected = !_isConnected;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final authProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>((ref) {
  return AuthProvider();
});

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  Future<void> setIsAuthenticated() async {
    _isAuthenticated = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _isAuthenticated = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class NoConnectionScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NoConnectionScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final connection = ref.read(connectionProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("This is the Not Connected Screen"),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Toggle Connection"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await connection.toggleConnection();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final auth = ref.read(authProvider);
    final conn = ref.read(connectionProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("This is the Login Screen"),
            Text(
              'Connected= ${conn.isConnected}\r\nAuthenticated=${auth.isAuthenticated}',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Toggle Connection"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await conn.toggleConnection();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Login"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await auth.setIsAuthenticated();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CheckScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final auth = ref.read(authProvider);
    final conn = ref.read(connectionProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("This is the CheckScreen"),
            Text('Connected= ${conn.isConnected}\r\nAuthenticated=${auth.isAuthenticated}'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Toggle Connection"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await conn.toggleConnection();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Logout"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await auth.logout();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Go to the Main Screen"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/main-screen');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final auth = ref.watch(authProvider);
    final conn = ref.watch(connectionProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("This is the Main Screen"),
            Text(
              'Connected= ${conn.isConnected}\r\nAuthenticated=${auth.isAuthenticated}',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Toggle Connection"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await conn.toggleConnection();
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Logout"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await auth.logout();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I need a way to globally monitor the state of authentication and connection and react to them regardless of which screen I'm on.**

I tried using Consumer widgets in the MaterialApp and using a Key for the MaterialApp that had the state of authentication and connection but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ref.watch` instead of `ref.read` in the `build` method in the `CheckScreen`, `LoginScreen`, `NoConnectionScreen` widgets.
2. It is not at all clear from your code how you are using the `connectivity_plus` package. Did you put a wire on him?
3. Try using a separate widget like `HomeApp` instead of the `getHome` method, with the `build` method `watch`ing for `authProvider` and `connectionProvider`.

Comment: 1- I tried it but it made no difference, 2- I forgot to remove the connectivity_plus from the sample code, the buttons in the screens simulate connecting and disconnecting, 3- I tried to make a separate widget instead of the getHome method but that made no difference.

Comment: The problem is when **Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/main-screen')** is called. the app stops responding to changes in **connectivity** or **authentication**